# Maximum recommended children in a Firebase Database node

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, nosql

I'm starting off with using Firebase Database for the first time, and I think I've got a decent structure planned out, but I'm worried about the number of child nodes I might end up with.

Is there a recommended limit or average known-good number of child values which can be added to a node without running into noticeable performance problems? I've not had much database experience at all, and I've not been able to find any information on what an acceptable value would be, so I have no idea if my planned structure will scale well.

As a rough estimate, I'm expecting a rough maximum of 30,000 children all-in. I'll only be requesting data from around 10 of those, but as far as I know, Firebase will retrieve the entire node, before filtering out any results, which is why I'm worried about the performance impact of retrieving the entire node. Any help with this would be massively appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As a rough estimate, I'm expecting a rough maximum of 30,000 children all-in.

That's not really a very large number of child nodes.

> as far as I know, Firebase will retrieve the entire node, before filtering out any results

If you query the database using a field with an index, the nodes will be filtered on the server.  [You can create an index to avoid performance problems for larger numbers of child nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).