# How many records can insert to one "child node" in "realtime database"?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Data store in the realtime database:

```
{     
     "users" : {
           "0c1592ca-0fa5-43b9-88d2-c9cd77b30611" : {
              "token" : "0cu9CJPb_DIUfbr-Ay8vh6:-KQXn....",
              "member_id" : "123456789102",
              "update_at" : "2021/06/14 08:08:08"
          },
           "36 random characters" : {
              "token" : "167 random characters",
              "member_id" : "12 random numbers",
              "update_at" : "YYYY/mm/DD HH:mm:ss"
          }
      }
    }
```

Let say a record is like this:

```
"36 random characters" : {
              "token" : "167 random characters",
              "member_id" : "12 random numbers",
              "update_at" : "YYYY/mm/DD HH:mm:ss"
}
```

How many records can insert into the "users" node like above?

Answer (score 1):

All limits of the Firebase Realtime Database are documented in the page [Realtime Database Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). If you study that page you'll find that there is no documented limit on the number of child nodes that can exist in a given path.

There is probably a physical limit on the system, a pricing limit for you, a limit on the number of nodes you can reasonably read, and a limit on the number of nodes the system can query (typically in the order of a couple of 100K to a couple of million nodes), but aside from those the system imposes no artificial limit on how many child nodes can exist under a path.

Note that this has been asked a few times before, so I also recommend reading:

- [Firebase Performance: How many children per node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712833/firebase-performance-how-many-children-per-node)
- [Maximum recommended children in a Firebase Database node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077854/maximum-recommended-children-in-a-firebase-database-node)